# Wandering shadows when DirectionalLight is attached to player object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get a directionalLight to move with the player. I do this to improve the shadow quality, so that the shadow camera's dimensions can be smaller. When the player moves the shadows wander a bit. It looks like it is not following the player close enough.

I have the following problem illustrated in this VERY POOR quality gif;
[image]

Is there a better way of doing this? Or did I forget to update something? Any advice is appreciated :)

In the player class I have an object where I attach the camera to and use that object as the target for the light. Then in the player.update function I set the light position with an offset to the object's position.

```
class Player{

    constructor(){
        this.object = new THREE.Object3D();
        scene.add( this.object );
        this.object.add( camera );

        this.directionalLightOffset = new THREE.Vector3(-5000, 2, 5);

        this.directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.85 );        
        scene.add( this.directionalLight);

        this.directionalLight.position.copy( this.directionalLightOffset );

        this.directionalLight.castShadow = true;
        this.directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 750; 
        this.directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 750;     
        this.directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = -2000;
        this.directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 2000;
        this.directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = -2000;
        this.directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = 2000;
        this.directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;    
        this.directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 90000;

        this.directionalLight.target = this.object;
    }

    update(){
        this.directionalLight.position.copy( this.object.position );
        this.directionalLight.add( this.directionalLightOffset );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh .. and forgot to mention... You also need to move the light.target point! Otherwise the light direction will change as you move.. you need to add the same offset to light.position And light.target!

Comment: Yes! but not ;p the target IS the player.object (which moves every frame). But I shouldn't do that with the solution you posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try only moving the camera in increments of your shadowmap pixel size or similar. Even just delaying how often you move the camera can minimize the shimmer.. so put a radius around the player and only reset the camera position when the player has wandered out of that radius.

Comment: This radius thing is a good idea! I will definitely try this tomorrow :D
One question though, How do i get shadowmap pixel size? I set the width and height, how do I get the pixel size from that? :S

Comment: So, for example; in the code I wrote above I set the width/height to 750, Once the player moves 750 units I should update the light's position?

Comment: Yeah pretty much something like that. There is a way to compute the exact texel size, but in the past, I've just eyeballed it with some made up scale factor. For non ortho lights, the size would vary based on the distance.. for Directional (ortho) you can figure The main thing is setting a wide enough area that you don't see the edges of the shadow map approaching under normal circumstances, but not so close that the frequency of the  snapping becomes noticable. In the straight down case, if you can get the snapping lined up on the lightmap texel boundary, it becomes pretty unnoticable.

Comment: Perfect :D Seems doable.

Comment: I figured the pixelsize would be the mapsize divided by the width or height of the camera's view.. :p

Comment: Might depend on the scale of the light.. and of course if light is not pointing straight down, then the pixel size varies across different axis.

Comment: That's a good point.. The easy solution of moving the light only when the player moves a certain distance worked like a charm :D thnx again!